# Do [T]EE and [T]BE have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, transformation, basis

I know there are plenty of questions regarding 2 matrices one is [T]BB and one is [T]EE , so we all know that eigenvalues and eigenvectors are kept across different bases.

My question is what happens when you have a transformation from one basis to another are the eigenvalues kept the same ?

For example i have one matrix that gets vectors relative to base B and the image is returned according to base E would its eigenvalues be exactly the same as the same transformation from E to E?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about math; I don't spot any programming

Comment: I meant it to be of linear algebra

Comment: Sorry for that..

Comment: Could you delete  it? I posted  it on math